# Is there a simple way to truncate tag text with an ellipses and add a link to delete at the end?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to smarten up the tags in my rails site. As of now, the link to delete appears on hover (achieved with CSS), but the table content would shift to accommodate the link. The idea to truncate the text to make space for the link was brought up.
[image: example goal]

From what I've read I don't think this can be done with CSS only. So I'm trying to recall JavaScript event listeners from my Intro days and I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out? Thanks

html.erb:

```
<div class='truncate'><%= t.name %></div>
<%= link_to 'x', remove_tag_contact_path(contact, t), remote: true, class: 'tag-remove crop-tag', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete the tag?' } %>
```

CSS:

```
.badge:not(:hover) > .tag-remove {
  opacity: 0;
}

.badge:hover > .tag-remove {
  color: #cc0000 ;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.badge-color {
  background-color: #A4A4A4;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function remove(el) {
  var element = el;
  element.remove();
}
```

```css
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="truncate">
    Iam really long text that needs to be truncated
  </div>
  <button class="btn" onclick="remove(this)">
    Cancel
  </button>
</div>
```

I might be misunderstanding but there is a way to truncate text using CSS.

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)

The trick is you would have to make sure that your text field has a proper width, EG

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="truncate">
  </div>
  <button>Cancel Me</Button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/m2gut7wo/)

Comment: Adding the .truncate to .badge:hover > .truncate has really put me on the correct path. I know I shouldn't say thanks but...thanks.